# How to send mail from HTML Form given on the website?

Tags: php, html

I don't know much HTML, need to send email using php.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Form Start-->
                <div class="contact_from">
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <!-- Message Input Area Start -->
                        <div class="contact_input_area">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message *" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn submit-btn">Send Now</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Message Input Area End -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my html form code, for sending mail query. I don't know how to trigger email, when someone clicks on the submit button.
Just tell me to initiate the function, I will do the mail sending task in php using sendgrid.

Comment: Form has _onsumbit_ event handler associated with it - try looking in this direction.

Comment: I don't know, how to do this?

Comment: use php mailer class, and search how to use it. for more info read [here..](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: What you need is AJAX that uses PHP mailer to send an email.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple.
Just add a form action to a custom php file.
The sendgrid documentation is itself too rich regarding the samples for integration options in PHP.
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html

Else if you're looking for the default email function of php then there's the king of web tutorials w3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Happy Coding.